# onCreate function not being called in firebase functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to invoke this firebase function (make) when there is a new user logged in and that user's details are entered in database.

```
export default class User extends React.Component{
render(){

constructor(){
super()
this.state = {
    phone: "",
    name: "",
  };
}

handleChange = (key) => (val) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: val });
  };

submitform = () => {
    if (this.state.phone.length > 8) {
      Alert.alert("Enter Proper ID number");
    } else if (this.state.name.length < 3) {
      Alert.alert("Enter Proper Name");
    } else {
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("users/" + this.state.phone)
          .set({ name: this.state.name, phone: this.state.phone });
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    }
  };

return (
<View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter ID"
          placeholderTextColor="black"
          value={this.state.phone}
          onChangeText={this.handleChange("phone")}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          placeholderTextColor="black"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChangeText={this.handleChange("name")}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>Enter</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
)
}
}
```

After submitting the form this firebase function should be executed

```
//firebase function code
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.make = functions.database.ref('users/').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const original = snapshot.val();
    console.log("function make called", original);
})
```

Here I am trying to just call the function and log it but i am not getting any output in the console of the firebase functions.

[Here is the database SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFn0r.png)

Here in this database whenever there is any modification or there is any update i want to call this above mentioned function. Here I am using real time database

Comment: Please **edit the question** to describe in more detail exactly what you're doing that should trigger the function.  If you're not creating a new node under "users", it will not trigger.

Comment: there is a new node created whenever there is a new user entered.

Comment: Please edit the question to be specific about *what* happens, not *when*. Show code or describe the process in detail but which data is added that should trigger the function.